# if else conditions in ckform joomla

Tags: joomla, components

I have installed the "CKFORMS" component in joomla, I want to put the condition on radio button (YES/NO) if it's checked to YES then the fields First Name and last name will become the mandatory for the user.

I don't know how should i proceed further.

Please help

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution,

I have included the Jquery inside the ckforms, and on the submit button , added the snippet to check if radio button is checked or not.

And if clicked yes, then all jquery stuff to stop the user (alert messages and son on).

thanks